# How to wait for axios function to return value when in service class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to structure my application with some sort of service class, but whenever I extract my axios calls from the page, then the axios function seems to return "undefined".

My page looks like this. The signin function is called when the user hits the button. When I put the axios call in the page like this, everything works fine. The usestate is updated and displays.

```js
export default function AccountPage() {
  const [signinResponse, setSigninResponse] = useState();

  async function signin() {
    await axios
    .get(
      `...url...`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setSigninResponse(res)
    });
  }
...
```

However, when I take the axios function and move it to a service class like this

```js
import axios from "axios";

export async function tableauSignin() {
  await axios
    .get(
      `...url...`
    )
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });
}
```

and then import and make the call like this

```js
import { tableauSignin } from "../services/tableau-online.service";
...
export default function AccountPage() {
  const [signinResponse, setSigninResponse] = useState();

  async function signin() {
    const r = await tableauSignin();
    setSigninResponse(r);
    console.log(r);
  }
...
```

the log from the service class is good but the log on the account page is undefined.

Comment: you forgot to `return` the Promise inside `tableauSignin`. So you could just add `return` before the `await` and this will work - but really there is then no point to the `async` or `await` at all, just make the function non-async and `return axios.get(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobinZigmond mentioned in comment. The following solution will work but it's a needless.

> it's a needless verbose way of just doing export function
> tableauSignin() { return axios.get(url).then(response =>
> response.data) }.

```
export async function tableauSignin() {
  return await axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)  
}
```

This Solution may be more useful

```
const getData = async () => {
    let res = await axios.get("url");
    let { data } = res.data; //or res
    return data;
};
```

You can also import this way

```
var response = await getData();
```

Comment: As I already said in my comment, while this will work, it's a needless verbose way of just doing `export function tableauSignin() { return axios.get(url).then(response => response.data) }`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond · you're right. i updating the answer.

Comment: You guys are saviors, thank you <3